# How to prove the conjugate of the conjugate function is itself?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose $f$ is closed and convex. $f^*$ is the conjugate of $f$. 
$$f^*(y)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \{y^Tx−f(x)\}$$
How to prove that $f=f^{**}$?

My thought:
I can write the conjugate by substitute terms into the definition as
$$\sup_a\{z^T a-\sup_x\{a^Tx-f(x)\}\}$$
But it seems cannot get any more simplification.

Comment: You should start with the definition of *.

Comment: You've been a user here for five years and posted dozens of questions. Please [edit] your question to actually show your own thoughts and efforts. Voting to close.

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks, The definition is added.

Comment: @user296602 Thanks, I have added my thought, though it seems a wrong direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem will be made simpler by translating to the language of convex sets.

Consider $\operatorname{epi} f$ and $\operatorname{epi} f^{**}$, the [epigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of $f$ and $f^{**}$.

To start, we have that both epigraphs are convex because $f$ and $f^{**}$ are closed and convex. To show that $f^{**}$ is closed and convex, consider that its epigaph is the intersection of (closed, convex) halfspaces of the form $\{z^{T} y - f^{*}(y): z \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, because supremum of functions results in the intersections of epigraphs.

We have that $f^{**} \leq f$. From its definition,
$$f^{**}(x) = \sup_{y} x^{T} y - f^{*}(y)$$
$$= \sup_{y} \{ x^{T} y - \sup_{z} \{ y^{T} z - f(z) \} \}$$
$$= \sup_{y} \, \inf_{z} \,y^{T}(z-x) + f(z) \leq \inf_{z} \, \sup_{y} \,y^{T}(z-x) + f(z) = f(x)$$
where the inequality comes from exchanging the infimum and supremum (you may also recall this maneuver from the proof of weak duality).

Now assume for contradiction that $f \neq f^{**}$. From our just-derived inequality, this means that $\exists x$ with $f^{**}(x) < f(x)$. By the closed/compact version of the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), there must be hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that strictly separates $\operatorname{epi} f$ from $(x, f^{**}(x))$.

This hyperplane cannot be vertical and strictly separate $\operatorname{epi} f$ from $(x, f^{**}(x))$, so we can normalize the normal vector of the hyperplane to be $1$ in the vertical component. This strict separation gives, for some $\epsilon > 0$ and non-vertical component $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of our hyperplane,
$$f(z) - \epsilon \geq y^T(z-x) + f^{**}(x) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$$
Some manipulations give
$$y^{T}x - f^{**}(x) - \epsilon \geq y^{T} z - f(z) \quad \forall z$$
and taking the supremum in $z$ yields
$$y^{T} x - f^{**}(x) - \epsilon \geq f^{*}(y).$$
Another manipulation gives
$$y^{T} x - f^{*}(y) - \epsilon \geq f^{**}(x).$$

Expanding the definition of $f^{**}$, we have just shown that
$$y^{T} x - f^{*}(y) - \epsilon \geq \sup_{v}\, v^{T} x - f^{*}(v).$$
Obviously the choice of $y$ on the LHS cannot exceed the supremum on the right, so we have our contradiction.

Comment: Is there a minor typo? Though it won't make a difference.
\begin{align}
    \sup_y\left\{x^T y - \sup_z\left\{y^Tz - f(z)\right\}\right\}&=\sup_y\left\{-\sup_z\left\{y^Tz -f(z) -y^Tx\right\}\right\}\\
    &=\sup_y\left\{\inf_z \left\{-y^T(z-x)+f(z)\right\}\right\}\\
    &=\sup_y\left\{\inf_z \left\{y^T(x-z)+f(z)\right\}\right\}
\end{align}

Comment: @Silentmovie but then wouldn't we have $f(z) - \epsilon \geq y^T(x-z) + f^{**}(x) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$?

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. Do you know something about the case where the domain is a Banach space (instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$)?